# How to change country flag?

Tags: vpn, proxy, ip, teamspeak

How to hide the IP from TeamSpeak and change country flag?

I tried using Spotflux but it prevented TeamSpeak from connecting the server.

I tried using SocksV4 proxy, but TeamSpeak bypassed the proxy somehow.

How can I change my IP in TeamSpeak? Please make sure your  answer is *mac compatible* and *free*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any proper VPN configuration that alter a default gateway in the routing table and allow UDP traffic will work. 
 OpenVPN software and a service provider such as VPNBook would suite your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use every type of VPN Connection, i would recommend ghostvpn its free and you can hide your real ip.